# how to display custom attribute on category page in GRID and LIST mode

Tags: php, magento2, categories, custom-attributes

how to display custom attribute below product name on category page in GRID and LIST mode 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set attribute property "used in product listing" to "Yes" from magento admin panel and then you can call value of your custom attribute in "list.phtml" file.

Path: Stores -> Attributes -> Product -> Edit Custom Attribute -> Store front properites -> Used in Product Listing -> Yes.

Comment: This doesn't help for category page